# GCC: Update from 4.9 to 8.x causes error: 'min' was not declared in this scope

Tags: gcc, g++

I updated from Debian Jessie to Buster and now the shared code libraries (shared across Windows, Linux, etc..) build are broken in Linux (the library is over 20 years old, why break it).

The module it was building was .cpp, is there a switch to get it to use `min()` as it was before.  I'd rather not put a macro in the main header as it triggers a rebuild across all other platforms and the library is very large.  No way can I force it to use std:min because other environments may use older compilers.

MORE INFORMATION:

This seems to be occurring if I include the following:

**#include <stdlib.h>**

TIA!!

Answer (score 1):

The new `stdlib.h` will undefine `min()/max()` so I worked around it by including `stdlib.h`early in a gccfix up header I already had.  In that header I already defined `min()/max()` if missing.

```
#if defined(__cplusplus)
#include <stdlib.h>
#endif

#ifndef max
#define max(a,b)            (((a) > (b)) ? (a) : (b))
#endif

#ifndef min
#define min(a,b)            (((a) < (b)) ? (a) : (b))
#endif
```

Now the build is running.